# Can connect using SQL Developer, but cannot connect using SQL*PLUS (ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, ora-01034, ora-27101

I recently installed Oracle Database 18c.

I have no problem connecting to the database using SQL Developer.

However, when I try to connect using SQL*PLUS, I'm given the error messages in the subject headline.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Here is my listener.ora:

```
 listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Algonquin\OracleDB18cExpressEdition\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Algonquin\OracleDB18cExpressEdition\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Algonquin\OracleDB18cExpressEdition\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )

    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Algonquin\OracleDB18cExpressEdition\dbhomeXE)
    )


  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = NewUser-PC)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default icon to access SQLPlus, have tried sys as sysdba and it gives you some kind of can't connect error, open a regular command window and simply type at the prompt C:/>**sqlplus / as sysdba**. That worked for me. The former method using the default icon for SQLPlus, had me hunting down articles to troubleshoot that error code and led me to where you are, editing your ORA files. WIth XE, turns out you don't even need to be in there but, thanks to that initial error code, well.